# change thumb image to original image in the product details page in vituemart and joomla

Tags: image, joomla, virtuemart

I am using joomla 1.5. I integrated virtuemart in my joomla application. If I add some images for some products, it is showing exactly in the listing page of the product from front-end. But if i click on the product, then it is showing the details of the product. In the detail page, I need the original image instead of thumbnail image. 
can you please guide me, how to change the thumbnail image to original size of image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Virtuemart 2 then navigate to
root/components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default_images.php

something like

```
<?php   echo $this->product->images[0]->displayMediaFull('class="medium-image" id="medium-image"', false, "class='", true); ?>
```

would do the trick,